# Error with partially installed package

Tags: apt, dpkg

I was recently trying to install php on my pi:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-cli php5-fpm
```

It ran for awhile and then froze. I had to leave so I left my laptop open and when I got back, it had disconnected, and php wasn't fully installed (but did have a man page entry).

Now, when I try to run it, I get this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I do, and it gets this:

```
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
```

and freezes. It does not return control of the console to me. I have to close the terminal window, and it takes a minute or so before I can ssh back into the pi.

I followed the instructions here to delete the systemd-journal group:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295123/warning-because-addgroup-tries-to-create-an-already-existing-user-group

I can then run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a', but when I do, it says "Done" but doesn't give me control of the console, and freezes.

So now I cannot install php on my pi. What should I do?

Edit: pertinent info from /etc/os-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a heavily customized OS, i would advice to start again from a fresh raspbian (or whatever OS you use). IMO it's a quicker, easier and more reliable way of solving your problem than to analyse logs and forums for hours, for an unpredictabnle result.

For the php part, your command seems to be fine ... if php5 is still available. Maybe you can find the "php" version of your packets (php=php7) instead of the "php5" your are tring to install.

Please post your OS and version so we can check this point.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. I was hoping to avoid that though :/

I edited the post with OS info. Thanks!